# How to deploy openbazaar-go to heroku

Tags: go, heroku, heroku-cli, heroku-api

How can I deploy openbazaar-go to heroku?

I got the go project `go get github.com/OpenBazaar/openbazaar-go`

Created heroku git `heroku create`

Push git changes `git push heroku master`

But getting error

```
remote: -----> Checking Godeps/Godeps.json file.
remote: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2504, column 8
remote:  !!    Bad Godeps/Godeps.json file
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Go app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to pacific-stream-51465.
```

Structure go

```
github.com
└──OpenBazaar
   └── openbazaar-go
        └──`heroku create` (this I created git project)
```

This project have any subrepository

Comment: I haven't used/deployed `openbazaar-go`. But there's a git conflict message committed to the repo [here](https://github.com/OpenBazaar/openbazaar-go/blob/9e17a661e2afc25f7c630a79280bc99c51b77153/Godeps/Godeps.json#L2504).

This is also pointed out by the error message `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2504, column 8`. Please try to understand any error message that pops up and dig in a bit before posting for solutions.

Comment: I only deal with go. Is there any way to fix this error for me ?

Comment: I have opened an issue [here](https://github.com/OpenBazaar/openbazaar-go/issues/2089). They should be fixing it. Meanwhile you can fork the repository and fix it  yourself to test out your setup.

Comment: Thanks. i creating fork the project. 
Change Rev/ But it is not working

Answer (score 0):

What version of Golang are you using? OpenBazaar runs predominantly on 1.11 and isn't currently set up to work well on 1.13 and above.

Comment: go1.14.4. But localhost working and building is well.